# Transform sequence of lines into python list, using Vim?

Tags: python, regex, vim

Using Vim, in a file containing strings on successive lines:

```
bear
fox
jackie chan
```

What's a good, repeatable way to make a python list of strings:

```
['bear', 'fox', 'jackie chan']
```

Tried a kludgy sequence of regexs over the range (such as `:1,3s/^/'/`, `:1,3s/$\n/', /`, followed by pesky hand edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple substitutions and `:join` to accomplish this:

```
:%s/^\s*\zs.*/'&',/|'[,']j|s//[&]/
```

This will yield:

```
['bear', 'fox', 'jackie chan',]
```

Personally I like the trailing comma, but you can remove it with another substitution or `:normal` command:

```
%s/^\s*\zs.*/'&',/|'[,']j|s//[&]/|s/,]$/]
%s/^\s*\zs.*/'&',/|'[,']j|exe "norm! $x"|s//[&]/
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h \zs
:h :j
:h :norm
:h :exe
:h :bar
:h :range
:h '[
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ggcG                           change the whole buffer

<C-r>=string(split(@"))<CR>    insert a string representation of
                               the content of the unnamed register

<Esc>                          leave insert mode
```

Comment: Appears to yield `['bear', 'fox', 'jackie', 'chan']` not `['bear', 'fox', 'jackie chan']`

Comment: @jwco You can use a more sophisticated regex for the split, `^\s*\|\s*\n\s*`. Here it is in a command: `command! -range=% ToList execute "normal! ".(<line2>-<line1>+1)."cc\<c-r>=string(split(@@,'^\\s*\\<bar>\s*\\n\\s*'))\<cr>"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a macro:

```
qq0i'^[$a',^[
```

This wrap the line into a `'...',`

You can select all your lines and apply the macro with:

```
:normal! @q
```

Then you can add a `[` before the first line, a `]` after the last one and

```
vipJ
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
:s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/['\1', '\2', '\3']/
```

Comment: That only works for *eactly* 3 elements. This does *not* scale well to 4, 5 or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

With my **Join** plugin (https://github.com/sk1418/Join), you can join lines with separator. For the given example, you can do:

```
:%s/^\|$/'/g|%J ','
```

then manually add the `['` and `']` to `BOL and EOL`

or just

```
:%J "','"
```

then manually add `['` and `']` to `BOL` and `EOL`

Comment: Like a general solution. However, slight aversion to manually adding brackets